# How do you check the support for a specific CPU in the Linux or BSD kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, bsd

Assuming that I have the sources for my kernel and I know the name of a SoC or a CPU, how I can check that the hardware is supported without compiling and running ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you will find a single place in kernel sources that will list all kinds of hardware supported: CPU architectures, aux cards, peripheral devices etc. To get a better idea you may construct find commands in the kernel source to get an idea of the types of devices supported. One such place could be to look into the arch directory of your kernel:

```
find /usr/src/kernels/yourkernel/arch -type f -exec grep -i 'supported' {} \; -print
```

Another could be the include directory:

```
find /usr/src/kernels/yourkernel/include -iname "*.h" -exec grep -i 'supported' {} \; -print
```

And refine/narrow down your search from here.

A more efficient approach would be to look into documentation of the system.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, check the contents of `/proc/cpuinfo`.

In BSD I think the closest thing is `/sbin/sysctl hw`.

Comment: I would like to do this starting from the source of a given kernel.